How can i show or hide an Image element if property is null in array map from returned array?
As you can see, the property mainImage in the array is null and it gives me the error:

Error: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'url')

I wanted to show or hide the Image element if the mainImage property in the array is null.
return (
<Container maxWidth="desktop">
  <Typography variant="h1" sx={{ mb: 10 }}>
    Blog
  </Typography>
  <Stack gap={5} useFlexGap>
    {articles.map((article: Article) => (
      <Box key={article._id} sx={{ display: "flex", gap: 3 }}>
        <Box
          sx={{
            position: "relative",
            aspectRatio: "16/9",
            flexShrink: 0,
            width: "30%",
          }}
        >
          <NextImage
                src={article.mainImage.url}
                alt={article.title}
                placeholder="blur"
                blurDataURL={
                  article.mainImage?.metadata?.lqip?.toString() ?? ""
                }
                fill
                style={{
                  objectFit: "cover",
                }}
          />
        </Box>
        <Box>
          <Typography variant="h2" sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
            <Link
              href={`/blog/${article.slug}`}
              component={NextLink}
              underline="hover"
            >
              {article.title}
            </Link>
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" sx={{ mb: 2 }}>
            By: {article.author}
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2">{article.excerpt}</Typography>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    ))}
  </Stack>
</Container>

);
Sample Data Returned:
[
{
    excerpt: "omitted",
    mainImage: null,
    categories: null,
    _id: '3453',
    _createdAt: '2024-12-11T16:39:29Z',
    title: 'omitted',
    slug: 'omitted',
    author: 'omitted'
  },
]


Thanks for all the response. I have now resolved it by adding the code below:
{article.mainImage?.url && (
            <NextImage
              src={article.mainImage.url}
              alt={article.title}
              placeholder="blur"
              blurDataURL={
                article.mainImage?.metadata?.lqip?.toString() ?? ""
              }
              fill
              style={{
                objectFit: "cover",
              }}
            />
          )}


You can check if it's null before you render the <NextImage /> component
{
  article.mainImage && <NextImage {...otherProps} />
}

